Script to initiate VPN session with openconnect on Windows 10
I am trying to automate the VPN connection through Openconnect.exe (given a password and TOTP) with a Windows PowerShell script. Unfortunately, I have not managed to supply the password to --passwd-on-stdin correctly, so I wondered, if a pro-user had been more successful.
Thank you in advance for sharing your approach to this tedious task.

Many systems do not allow unencrypted passwords to be used and required a credential where the password is encrypted.

An update to the most recent version of openconnect, 9.12 at the time of writing, solved the issue. Get-Content pw.txt | openconnect https://target.url --user myname --passwd-on-stdin now works as expected in PowerShell.
